# Local Virtualhost Always Results in Search Lookup in Firefox

Tags: apache, firefox, browser, dns, virtualhost

I am setting up some local virtualhosts for developments.

In particular, I have the following two sites enabled.

1. `<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sites.dev
       ServerAlias sites.dev
       DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/
       <Directory />
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride None
       </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/sites>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`
2. `<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName xxx.dev
       ServerAlias xxx.dev
       DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/xxx/
       <Directory />
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/sites/xxx>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`

Where `xxx` is some word.

When I enter `sites.dev` in the browser address bar, I am successfully taken to the local site. However, when I enter `xxx.dev`, I am taken to a URL that looks like this `http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http%3A//xxx.dev/&r=&bc=`.

That is, it seems to me that the browser is trying to do a look-up on it. How could I fix it or make the browser look locally instead?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=dnsrsearch might help with one part of the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly due to some plugin installed on your browser. Try in incognito mode.

Also make sure you have a local host file entry pointing to localhost for your xxx domain.